# Packet Sniffer to dynamically create iptables rules

Tags: iptables, bash, routing, unix, packet-sniffer

On a router running unix I wish to make monitor all outgoing packets, of these packets I want to temporarily white list IP addresses I am connecting to, to both send and receive.

Basically to create a pinhole in a firewall that normally would drop all incoming packets (drops all packets except white listed ones, which were white listed by this script based on ips I send a packet to connect to).  In looking around I could make a bash script based off a packet sniffer, but is there a way to do it within iptables itself and not have to involve a packet sniffer and bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists in the form of the Connection Tracking module in iptables.  [This Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands) describes this and contemporary distributions often implement this by default.

Before doing this be sure you have a way to get back in if you lock yourself out.

Essentially:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s YOUR-TRUSTED-HOST -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT -j DROP
```

All incoming packets are dropped unless they relate to an established connection.

A shell based mechanism is likely to be too slow to keep up with the rate at which machines create connections.